# Linux Mint 20 in Docker

Tags: docker, linux-mint

I would like to do some testing and build some of my codes before I switch to Mint 20. Using Docker seems to be a good choice. Strangely I can't find any Docker images or tutorials on how to install *any* Mint in a Docker.
It seems to me there's no method also for a terminal-only installation of the newer Mints.

Comment: Containers are normally used for "lightweight", none GUI distro. Light enough to run just one application service. This maybe why you are having difficulty finding an image.

Comment: @RamanSailopal - that's correct. Yet all other major Linux Distributions offer some kind of Docker-Image. I wonder why Mint doesn't

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxmintd/mint20-amd64

Comment: @RamanSailopal - awesome, thank you! Just interesting - they install Mint via Ubuntu: https://github.com/clefebvre/docker-images/blob/master/mint20.1-amd64.Dockerfile

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/vcatechnology/linux-mint 50k pulls

Answer (score 1):

For such usecase, you can use free tool Oracle virtualBox.

Comment: How does this answer my question?